# INSERT INTO SELECT Troubleshooting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When using INSERT INTO SELECT, the SELECT portion if run on its own returns in about 25 seconds. THE INSERT INTO I've let go for over 8 mins and then cancelled. What can I do to start troubleshooting this? I'm not sure if there is locking going on? This is a table that has constant single selects and inserts going on. There are also 3 index on this table that I know need to be updated when new rows come in. The scenario above is also for only 68,000 rows, and I do have other inserts that I will need to do that will contain more. Last, I'm using SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you shoe the structure of the table?

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the table? If so, check if any of them is messing with you (infinite loop). My bet goes that way.

Comment: What do the execution plans say?

Comment: No triggers and if I run an execution plan there is a key look up at 74% at the beginning. The same key lookup if I run the SELECT on its own. Then everything down the line is minor but there are 2 Table Spools at a cost of 30% before the insert into one of the Indexes. I only know so much when it comes to reading the plans.

Comment: Is your select from the same table you are inserting?

Comment: No as I said above I have a table I've added that contains all the rows. This table is not being used by anything, is used as a temp location and will be dropped after the rows have been inserted into the destination table.

Comment: Any suggestions as to table lock hints?

Comment: Guessing game here, but it might be that your 68k rows Insert is trying to escalate it's locks from pages to whole table and constant small inserts are preventing that. Try with ALTER TABLE table_name SET (LOCK_ESCALATION=DISABLE). It will disable escalation, so your insert query might work a bit slower but it should finish

Comment: Also run SELECT allow_page_locks, allow_row_locks FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('your_table') to check if any of your indexes does not allow for page or row locks. If any of them have 0 in these columns, you'll have to rebuild it with allow options.

Comment: What is lock escalation for exactly and what will the ramifications been if disabled for a period of time?

Comment: allow_page_locks and allow_row_locks are all set to value of 1

Comment: Do you have enough available space in the data and log files/drives?  Breaking your insert into more manageable chunks often helps.  Have you tried using bcp with the -b (batch size) option?

Comment: Since we wanted to move this data to a separate server, I decided to go that route. I was able to link the servers and move the data.

Answer (score 0):

Is there space for the new table?  I had a project way back in SQL Server 2000.  The auto-growth was killing the timing.  When I pre-allocated the space before loading, the process flew.

Make sure your growth options are not 1 mb or 10 %.  That will kill you also.

Also, look into instant database file initialization.  If this is turned off, the SQL Server engine has to zero out the pages before giving you new space.  Otherwise, it skips this step.

Good link from MSDN on this topic,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg634626.aspx

Trace Flag 1806 which disables Instant Database File Initialization.  Make sure this is not set on your server.

Please post back if this does not fix your issue.

Sincerely

John 
The Crafty DBA
[www.craftydba.com](http://www.craftydba.com)